# Linq query to filter a list of strings in Observable collection

Tags: .net, list, observablecollection

From the Observable collection I want to filter the items with names aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee. How to do this?

```
public class Item
{
public string ItemName {get; set;}
public int ItemNumber {get; set;}
}

public ObservableCollection<Item> _items;

public List<string> searchItems = new List<string>(5);
searchItems.Add("aaa");
searchItems.Add("bbb");
searchItems.Add("ccc");
searchItems.Add("ddd");
searchItems.Add("eee");
```

I tried a bit in linq.. But I dont know how to do for a list..

```
var filteredItems = from item in _items
                    where _items.Any(x => x.ItemName == "aaa")
                    select x;
```

Comment: Highly recommend you use `Hashset<string> searchItems` as-well, especially if you have lots of search terms.

Comment: @MeirionHughes: I will have at Max 15 items. Whether I need to change to hashset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Contains;

```
var filteredItems = from item in _items
                    where _items.Any(x => searchItems.Contains(x.ItemName))
                    /*select x;*/
                    select item;
```

Comment: var filteredItems = from item in _items
                    where _items.Any(x =>x. searchItems.Contains(x.ItemName))
                    /*select x;*/
                    select item;